# Include a function with render in another view function

Tags: python, django, error-handling, django-views

I want to design an error handler function in view and use it in different main functions in view.
This error handler function will gather required error info, log the error to the system, and render those info to an error handler page.

Codes in view.py look like:

```
def error_manage(request, error_title, error_detail):
    error_time = datetime.now()
    info_table = {'error_title': error_title,
                     'error_detail': error_detail,
                     'error_time ': error_time ,
                     }
    logger.error(str(error_detail))
    return render(request,'home/error_manage.html', {'error_title': error_title, 
                                                     'info_table ': display_table})


def my_page_1(request):
    try:
        var1 = my_calculation_func()
    except Exception as ex:
        error_manage(request, "Unexpected Error Happened.", ex)
    
    var2 = my_calculation_func2()
    var3 = my_calculation_func3()
    return render(request,'home/my_page_1.html', {'var1': var1 ,'var2': var2 ,'var3': var3})
```

The problem here is that when the error occurs in var1, the program will jump into error_manage but will not stop in the return of this function and also will not successfully render into error_manage.html.

it will later jump out of this function and continue run var2 and var3 until it meets the final return in my_page_1().

I know I can simply put the return statement in error_manage to my_page_1 under Exception.
But this error handler will be used in many other functions in view.py and I don't want to repeat it over and over again.

Is there a good solution for this problem? Thank you.

Comment: I'd write your error handler as a decorator function and then use it as a decorator on the views that you want to use it for.

Comment: Maybe you need to `raise` custom exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of the decorator approach:

```
class MyError(Exception):
    pass


def error_handler(func):
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except MyError as e:
            return f"Oh no! {e} happened!"
    return decorated


@error_handler
def my_view(request):
    if "error" in request:
        raise MyError("request was rubbish")
    return "Great success!"


for r in ["Fine", "no problem", "An error happened"]:
    print(my_view(r))
```

So running this, we get

```
Great success!
Great success!
Oh no! request was rubbish happened!
```

So essentially we use the decorator to catch and handle MyError exceptions, other exceptions will not be handled and will bubble up out of the view as normal to be handled by django's [default] view error handling.

Comment: love the use of decorators - not sure why this was thumbed down

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to implement this in my codes, but I got one question: I can put the error variables I want to render, such as error_detail (by error_detail=str(e)) and error_time (by error_time = datetime.now()), under the "except " line of def error_handler() and then render to the error handling page I want. 

But how I can pass the error_title which is pretty customized depending on different error situations. (In my question case, it is "Unexpected Error Happened." but it could be different for other error cases)

Comment: If you want a different error message per view, then you could use a **parameterised decorator**: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/decorators-with-parameters-in-python/

Answer (score 2):

You should make a custom middleware to handle exceptions. See [Writing your own middleware [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware):

```py
class MyMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
    
    def process_exception(request, exception):
        error_time = datetime.now()
        info_table = {
            'error_detail': exception,
            'error_time ': error_time ,
        }
        logger.error(str(exception))
        return render(request,'home/error_manage.html', {'info_table ': display_table})
```

Now you need to add this middleware to the `MIDDLEWARE` list in the settings:

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # Default middlewares
    'path.to.MyMiddleware',
]
```

Now in your view you should simply not catch the Exception and let the middleware handle it.

> **Note**: With this your approach of passing `error_title` won't work but you can try to re-raise a new exception from the old one if you
> need some customization: `raise Exception("Unexpected Error Happened.") from ex`

Comment: The problem with this is that it's applied to *every* view, which may not be what the OP wants.

Comment: @TomDalton yes but nothing that can't be solved with some if-else. The `request` is passed to `process_exception` so it can easily be figured out which view raised this exception. :)

Comment: True, but then you're coupling your middleware to the specific app, when (personally) I'd want middleware to be doing more generic/general stuff.

Comment: @TomDalton error handling is general stuff though. Which is why the `process_exception` method even exists on middlewares...

Comment: Yep, I'm not saying this is outright wrong, I'm just saying it's not clear from the OP whether they want every view to be automatically handled in this way. Maybe they do, maybe they don't.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try whether this solution matches my case.